# C++ open source projects

Tags: c++, open-source

I'm looking for a suitable open source project to work on in C++. It really can be anything.

My background is in gaming, on both PC and consoles; but I'd prefer to work on something low latency or real time. I'm also interested in Math stuff.

Do any of you guys have suggestions?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/people/

Comment: There are too many possible answers here. This is typically something you'll want to figure out yourself by just browsing through existing open source projects.
Be sure to download some sourcecode, and see if you like working on it.
Good starting points are GitHub, SourceForge and perhaps even freshmeat.

Comment: I work on this open source project if you're interested: www.scirra.com

Answer (score 4):

You may want to take a look at [FlightGear](http://www.flightgear.org) which is an open source flight simulator that is cross-platform software (which does however not run on any console), but it being a flight simulator, it can be surely considered "low latency" or "real time". It is written in C++ and has a number of dependencies such as OpenSceneGraph, PLIB and uses OpenGL for cross platform rendering. There is a fairly [comprehensive developers section to be found at their wiki](http://wiki.flightgear.org/index.php/Portal:Developer) and they have a pretty active [community of users and developers](http://flightgear.org/forums) posting to their forums, and a dedicated [developers mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/flightgear-devel) at sourceforge.

There is also a gitorious mirror to get easily started cloning the repositories: http://gitorious.org/fg

Another possibility would be to post to the [GameDev.net forums](http://gamedev.net/community/forums) and ask there for further advice.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [GitHub](http://github.com/) and fork a project that interests you. You can also take over projects at [SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/).